# QGIS autodecrease ID (pkuid) number when the item is deleted

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have about 4000 elements, defined by ID. The ID is autoincremented by this formula:

```
    maximum(pkuid)+1
```

Everything is fine, but I had to delete some of the elements from "inside" my list. In turn, the final ID value is about 4140 whereas the total number of my elements hasn't exceeded 4000 yet.

[image]

Is it possible to make the autocorrections of ID for the values, which are "above" the deleted elements? I sorted my data attribute table by ID. I would like to have the final number ID the same as the total number of elements in my layer. Is it possible?

Comment: In general once you've allocated an ID it's bad practice to reallocate it to a different feature. Lots of things depend on them staying unique (indexes for example)

Comment: Do you mean, that the values might disappear for instance? If I sort them from 1 to 4000 they will be still unique.

Comment: You don't know who else is using those IDs - it will probably be fine but then again it might not be - why risk it? FIDs are internal so it doesn't matter.

Comment: In general I would not change ID's. However, if you do not intend to link the data to anything else, or cooperate with others (which you may in the future, even if you don't know yet) you can reassign the ID. I would create a new ID-field, sort by the old ID and use the formular 'row_number' to fill in the new field. You could do that on the original ID-field as well, but I would not touch that.